# file not found error while using read_csv on a Jupyter notebook

Tags: python, jupyter

I get a file not found error while using the read_csv() function on a Jupyter notebook even when I have the exact path listed. Any pointers on why this happens? Googled it and one solution was to prefix the path with 'r' which worked. However why is this prefix required?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Help us help you - share the faulty code

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This is raw strings event. It is necessary on Windows operating systems when the path contains backslashes. Otherwise the backslash is treated as an escape character. For example, `"hello\nworld"` -- the `\n` means a newline. `r"hello\nworld"` literally means the characters `"hello\nworld"` And in this way we can see in the screen
`hello world`